# show, hide and destroy matplotlib.widgets

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created some widgets (buttons, slider, radiobuttons) on my pylab.figure and I want to let disappear some of them on a certain event. 
But when I look into the matplotlib.widgets-doc I can't find any way to hide (or at least destroy) my widgets. Is this possible?